# Katalon Studio fails to start application in Windows object spy

Tags: selenium, katalon-studio, winappdriver

I use `Katalon Studio 7.0.4` and `Windows Application Driver v1.2 RC` and allowed port 4723 on firewall. I used `PuTTY` for testing. Connection is successful, application is shown in spy tool, but got errors when try to use some methods(e.g.:click, getText). I see following errors in logs.

On server side:

```
==========================================
GET /session/3A8AB5F8-E6B3-4FB1-9C14-E48B8F4F5C4D/screenshot HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: myip:4723
User-Agent: selenium/3.141.59 (java windows)

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Error
Content-Length: 133
Content-Type: application/json

{"status":13,"value":{"error":"unknown error","message":"An unknown error occurred in the remote end while processing the command."}}


==========================================
GET /session/3A8AB5F8-E6B3-4FB1-9C14-E48B8F4F5C4D/window_handle HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: myip:4723
User-Agent: selenium/3.141.59 (java windows)


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 84
Content-Type: application/json

{"sessionId":"3A8AB5F8-E6B3-4FB1-9C14-E48B8F4F5C4D","status":0,"value":"0x000A09F4"}
```

On client side:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown error occurred in
> the remote end while processing the command. (WARNING: The server did
> not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 0
> milliseconds Build info: version: ‘3.141.59’, revision: ‘e82be7d358’,
> time: ‘2018-11-14T08:25:53’ System info: host: ‘LAPTOP’, ip:
> ‘192.168.56.1’, os.name: ‘Windows 10’, os.arch: ‘amd64’, os.version:
> ‘10.0’, java.version: ‘1.8.0_181’ Driver info:
> io.appium.java_client.windows.WindowsDriver Capabilities {app:
> C:\Users\user101\Downloads…, javascriptEnabled: true, platform:
> WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS} Session ID:
> 3A8AB5F8-E6B3-4FB1-9C14-E48B8F4F5C4D at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
> at
> io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
> at
> io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:46)
> at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1) at
> io.appium.java_client.windows.WindowsDriver.execute(WindowsDriver.java:1)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getScreenshotAs(RemoteWebDriver.java:295)
> at
> com.kms.katalon.composer.windows.spy.WindowsInspectorController.captureScreenshot(WindowsInspectorController.java:82)
> at
> com.kms.katalon.composer.windows.dialog.WindowsRecorderDialog$3.captureImage(WindowsRecorderDialog.java:653)
> at
> com.kms.katalon.composer.windows.dialog.WindowsRecorderDialog$3.run(WindowsRecorderDialog.java:620)
> at
> org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)

In Katalon Studio:
[image: Katalon Studio Windows Spy tool]

Comment: try your WinAppDriver and katalon studio both in Administrative mode.

Comment: I tried it already.